# Transformer turn ratio in DC-DC flyback converter for high voltage output

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, flyback

I have been for the past 3 months trying to design and experiment with topologies to charge a high voltage capacitor up to 1 kV. I have settled on a classic flyback topology:

[image: Flyback topology used and high voltage capacitor on output]

I have tried several transformers and understand how important elements such as the turn ratio, switching frequency, core type and leakage inductance impact my application. I struggle however to understand the following formula: Vo = N . Vi . D / (1-D), where D is the duty-cycle (D = ton. fSW).
This would imply that to get my high voltage capacitor up to 1 kV from a 12V source I would need an 83 turn ratio. However, I have seen multiple designs where a low turn ratio transformer is used to generate high voltage such as the following:

[image: 350V from a 12V input]

I found contradicting information left and right on the forum about a high turn ratio. I have read explanation to view the flyback topology from the perspective of energy transfer and that what I am looking at is delivering pulses of current on my secondary to gradually charge my capacitor to the desired voltage. Is there an assumption on the formula that I am missing? How is it possible that we can observe a high voltage on the output with low turn ratios?

Answer (score 4):

A flyback design whether step up or step down can operate in two modes of operation: -

- DCM (discontinuous conduction mode)
- CCM (continuous conduction mode)

In CCM your formula is correct but, in DCM, what you can transfer to the secondary is governed by this formula: -

[image]

Image from [my basic website, flyback section](http://stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html).

In other words, in DCM, whatever energy you transfer to the secondary gets used by the secondary and, can therefore continue to charge up a capacitor to whatever voltage you require.

This **cannot** happen in CCM because of the constraints imposed by switching waveforms. In other words, you cannot arbitrarily produce a larger output voltage without increasing the duty cycle, D.

In DCM, if you keep increasing \$R_L\$, in order to burn the energy transferred from the primary, a higher secondary DC voltage must be reached. It's all in the formulas.

Comment: @TimWilliams and Andy aka (you'll get notified as the post owner even without an `@`) - We would prefer site members to resolve minor disagreements themselves. However, the comments here been flagged and therefore we have to get involved. I'll move the previous comments into a chatroom and I plan to post some site usage information in that chatroom shortly, but not immediately (real life takes priority). It *should* be later tonight EU (UTC+2) time. I'll share the chatroom link & invite you both then. Please don't post further comments here. Thanks.